# python scoping and del

Tags: python, scope

I am having difficulty to understand how del works in python. 
Should not del delete the object a after print it's value ?

```
def f1():
    a = 5
    def f2():
        print('a: ', a)
        del a
    f2()
    print(a)

f1()
```

By executing this function I am getting error:

> UnboundLocalError: local variable 'a' referenced before assignment.

But if I don't delete a then it's working properly.

```
def f1():
    a = 5
    def f2():
        print('a: ', a)
        # del a
    f2()
    print(a)

f1()
```

Question:

1. is del working at the same time as printing?
2. if yes then it should be okay to understand but if not then is there anything I am missing?

Comment: It seems like adding the `del a` statement makes the variable `a` a local.  If you add `global a` before the `print('a: ', a)` it works as expected and deletes the global variable.

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47717277/how-to-delete-a-global-variable-from-inside-a-function) is a similar question.

Comment: thanks. it may be the reason, but does del really make a non-global variable a local one?

Comment: I am not sure to be honest.  That was just my initial thought.  Can anyone else explain?  Maybe it's a safety feature to stop you accidentally deleting a global variable.

Comment: Same reason as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49538724/why-is-ord-seen-as-an-unassigned-variable-here

Comment: That explains it.  Thanks @user3483203!  I guess `del a` is considered an assignment statement just like `a = 1`.

Comment: @Bill [Indeed](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/executionmodel.html#binding-of-names): "A target occurring in a `del` statement is also considered bound for this purpose (though the actual semantics are to unbind the name)."